# AWS Cognito: How to list out or revoke all previously issued tokens that have almost infinite expiration time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for my webapp and while I was learning for the first time, I did something silly:

In my user pool ---> App client, I set the token configurations as such:

> Refresh token expiration: 100 days
>
> Access token expiration: 1 day
>
> ID token expiration: 1 day

Some test engineers outside of my company (part-time workers) logged into the webapp and they have tokens with the above settings.

Now, I have set it to be more standard:

> Refresh token expiration: 60 minutes
>
> Access token expiration: 5 minutes
>
> ID token expiration: 5 minutes

While the newly issued refresh tokens will expire after 1 hour, the previously issued token are still valid. The test engineers can still login to the webapp since they have the tokens stored in local storage.

How can I invoke the previously issued "super" tokens and stop those users from login again?

Comment: How about this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-revocation.html?

Comment: @DevangSanghani  It requires me to know the refresh token to revoke it. Now the problem is that I do not know all the refresh tokens that have been issued out. Is there a way to list them out?

Comment: Just check from the console having the above expiration details?